# new line character in a json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

While fetching JSON object from an API like this, there is a new line character in id:7124, so I could not not fetch data wrt id.

How to remove that new line character?

```
 [  
   {  
      "Id":"7121",
      "Name":"Muthyalamadu(towards - pes)"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"7122",
      "Name":"Muthyalamadu(towards - aes)"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"7123",
      "Name":"Muthyalamadu(towards - des)"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"7124",
      "Name":"Muthyalamadu(towards  
    - kes)"
   }
]
```

Comment: there is a new line character in id:7124 after towards  -  kes appears in new line

Comment: replace it with empty string

Comment: Can you post you code also.It will be nice to know what you are doing?

Comment: The data is not valid JSON. Get the people who wrote the API to fix it.

Comment: The thing is that the string is not valid JSON. Instead of working around this and trying to fix the other party's fault, get *them* to fix it.

Comment: The JSON format expects a string to consist of a sequence of zero or more unicode characters **except `"` or ``\`` or control character**. The thing is, **line feeds and carriage returns are both control characters**.

Comment: var bmtc = require('bmtc-js-api');

bmtc.nearestStop(12.9566695,77.6867077,function(body){
    var result = body.toString();
    console.log(result);
  });
  
 now i want to fetch only all StopName

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this is not valid JSON, as described [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071727/new-line-character-in-a-json-object/52072081#comment91093409_52071727). But before parsing the `JSON` you could do two things:

**Remove the newlines**

```
response.replace(/\n/g, "");
```

**Or escape the newlines** (This will keep the data, but still parse as valid JSON)

```
response.replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Before doing `JSON.parse` on the response from the API - do a `response.replace(/\n/g,"")` to remove all unescaped new lines.

---

To filter out everything besides stop names from the response:

```
response = response.map(function(stop)
{
  return stop.Name;
});
```

Comment: That will only remove the first unescaped new line.

Comment: var bmtc = require('bmtc-js-api');

bmtc.nearestStop(12.9566695,77.6867077,function(body){
    var result = body.toString();
    console.log(result);
  });
  
  now i want to fetch only all StopName